# Replace blank and zero prices in WooCommerce product variations with text - tried a few options only getting "N/A"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know this question has been asked before on several forums and I have a few versions of php to add to the functions file but none work.

If I give a variation a value of 0 or leave it blank, it just shows N/A on the site and I would like to show alternative text. I'm also curious as to where it gets the N/A from, as I thought I could just change that to POA instead.

Here are the three snippets I am testing, I'd appreciate any guidance. I am not a professional btw and I'm trying to work on a site that has been customised by someone else! Thanks!

// Variable and simple product displayed prices - this is currently in the file originally added by A

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_html', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_html( $price, $product ) {
$empty_price = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce');
if( $product->is_type('variable') )
{
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    if ( empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
        return $empty_price; // <=== HERE below for empty price
    } else {
        $min_price     = current( $prices['price'] );
        $max_price     = end( $prices['price'] );
        if ( $min_price === $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for zero price
        }
        elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
            return wc_price( $max_price );
        }
    }
}
elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
{
    if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {
        return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices
    }
}
return $price;
}
```

OR

// Product Variation displayed prices added by Claire 24/08/2020 OPTION 1

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html', 10, 3);
function empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {

if( '' === $variation->get_price() || 0 == $variation->get_price() )
    $data['price_html'] = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce'); // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices

return $data;
}
```

OR

// Product Variation displayed prices added by Claire 24/08/2020 OPTION 2

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_display', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_display( $price, $product ) {
$blank_price = __('Price not yet set', 'woocommerce');
$zero_price = __('Free', 'woocommerce');

if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) {
        return $blank_price;
    } else if (0 == $product->get_price() ) {
        return $zero_price;
    }
}
return $price;
}
```